# ASP.NET MVC lowercase routes in parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "CompanyDefault",
        url:  "Company",
        defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute( 
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

It works fine when I write like this:

```
@Url.Action("ApplicationDriverForm", "ApplicationDriver")
```

but when I try to do it with parameter:

```
@Url.Action("ApplicationDriverForm", "ApplicationDriver", new { PaRaMeTeRwithUppercaseLetters = "BlaBlaBla" })
```

then in this case it generates url with uppercase letters in the name of parameter and the value of parameter

How to make it to generate lowercase letters in parameters too?

Comment: Your have not shown a route which matches the url your trying to create

Comment: it's a default route             routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route your matching (the `Default` route) has a segment placeholder for a value named `{id}`

Your `@Url.Action()` code is generating a value for a parameter named `PaRaMeTeRwithUppercaseLetters` which does not match your route, therefore the value is added as a query string, not a route value.

Either change the code for generating the url to

```
@Url.Action("ApplicationDriverForm", "ApplicationDriver", new { id = "BlaBlaBla" })
```

or add a specific route definition to match the url (before the default route)

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    name: "ApplicationDriver",
    url: "ApplicationDriver/ApplicationDriverForm/{PaRaMeTeRwithUppercaseLetters}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ApplicationDriver", action = "ApplicationDriverForm" }
);
```